# How to change column type of data frame in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to change column type in data frame from **integer** to **double** using sparkR. while typecasting using **cast()** function getting below error.

```
printSchema(df)
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
```

---

**Code**:

```
> df$col2 <- cast(df$col2, "double")
```

---

**Error**:

```
Error in data[subset, , drop = FALSE] : 
      object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with `pyspark` than `SparkR` but I think you should do:

```r
df <- withColumn(df,"col2",cast(df$col2,"double"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Now i able to fix the above error by adding **SparkR::** before cast() method.

```
> df$col2 <- SparkR::cast(df$col2, "double")
```